# Using a while case statement in a repeat while loop

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out how to use a case statement in a repeat while loop. It is working in the plain while loop but not in the repeat while loop.

```
indirect enum Ancestor {
    case son(name: String)
    case father(name: String, Ancestor)
}
```

Create some enum objects and setup the recursive relationships

```
let greatGrandson: Ancestor = .son(name: "Sam")
let grandson: Ancestor = .father(name: "David", greatGrandson)
let father: Ancestor = .father(name: "John", grandson)
let grandFather: Ancestor = .father(name: "Robert", father)
```

Recursively process and print the enum

```
var relation = grandFather
while case Ancestor.father = relation  {
    switch relation {
    case .son(let name):
        fatalError("this should not happen")
    case .father(let name, let thisRelation):
        print("father - \(name)")
        relation = thisRelation
    }
}
if case .son(let name) = relation {
    print("son \(name)")
}
```

The problem is that doing a while does not work properly because it will check the condition and kick out the son before it is processed. So I wanted to do a repeat while loop with the case check

The following repeat while loop doesn't compile.

```
repeat {
    switch relation {
    case .son(let name):
        print("son - \(name)")
    case .father(let name, let thisRelation):
        print("father - \(name)")
        relation = thisRelation
    }
} while case Ancestor.father = relation
```

Even though in the ***straight while loop*** the while case statement works but in the ***repeat while loop*** I get the following error

> Enum 'case' is not allowed outside of an enum

What am I doing wrong, why can't I use a while case in a repeat while loop?

Comment: I repro'd this issue. Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/statements/#While-Statement), the **while statement** is much more capable than the **repeat-while statement**.

[image: Grammar of a while statement]
[image: Grammar of a repeat-while statement]

The **repeat-while** expects a *Bool expression*.

A very ugly workaround is to put the *case condition* into an *if statement* in a *closure* and call it:

```
repeat {
    switch relation {
    case .son(let name):
        print("son - \(name)")
    case .father(let name, let thisRelation):
        print("father - \(name)")
        relation = thisRelation
    }
} while ({ if case Ancestor.father = relation { return true }; return false }())
```